# Why can't compiled language have "eval" function?

Tags: c++, c, compilation, eval

Yesterday I started a discussion with a friend of mine about this issue. He is used to code in interpreted languages (AS3, PHP), which have eval functions, and I got used to use compiled languages (such as C++).
Then, I tried to explain him that, to have eval functionality in compiled languages is impossible, because native code, does not know anything about its source code (variables, syntax, reflection (in case of C/C++) and so on) and that way, you can not make any function to take source code to be executed in real time without compile (and to compile it, you need the rest of source code, so it is impossible).

What do you think? Is this argument solid enough? Will you give any other arguments to argue why a compiled language can't have eval functionality? (Please, don't post stuff for nor against eval idea).

Comment: Assumes facts not in evidence. There are compiled lisps, and lisp's code-is-data philosophy *is* eval.

Comment: Common Lisp has `eval`, and most implementations I know of are compiled.  Therefore, your initial premise is wrong.

Comment: Basically, yes, your argument is solid enough; a compiled C/C++ program does not know the names of its variables, constants, functions. Everything has been evaluated at compile time. That's about it. But then, there's LISP.

Comment: the [Tiny C Compiler](http://repo.or.cz/w/tinycc.git) works pretty well as a backend for `eval()` if you don't mind compiler bugs from time to time (it has been used to compile and boot linux on-the-fly)...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Compiled languages can have `eval`, but the binary will need to contain, or have access to, a compiler as well.

If the `eval`ed code is to interact with the compiled code, then some annotations (e.g. variable names, class names, function names, types) in the binary are necessary. Java `.class` files are a good example where a lot of information can still be gathered from the compiled code alone.

Comment: Though Java is not a good example, as it is interpreted, I see this as a good reasoning to answer that.

Comment: Depends how you interpret "interpreted". Java is compiled down to bytecode which is interpreted by a virtual machine; but the actual source code is not interpreted at runtime at all.

Comment: Also, JVM can have an hardware implementation, and several flavors of ARM can run byte-code directly.

Comment: Varnish is an example, since it's config values are practically evaled at startup :)

Comment: @Thomas: don't forget that it often is being JITed

Answer (score 11):

Compiled languages certainly can have an eval function (like LISP), but it means that the runtime has to contain the compiler.

In fact, JavaScript is probably the best example of this. All [major implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines) (V8, Charkra, SpiderMonkey) now compile to native code, but it has an `eval` function. This works because the compiler is part of the runtime system.

Comment: That's a pretty wildly different notion of "compiled" from the one that applies to C or C++, AFAIK...

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: By "wildly different", do you mean "no manual invocation of the compiler"?

Comment: I mean that bytecodes for a virtual machine are quite removed from CPU opcodes. The VM works fundamentally differently.

Comment: I think what he is saying is that when compiled and optimized, executable binary does not know anything about its high level symbol names, and thus, limiting the posible eval much.

Comment: @Gabe JavaScript core is indeed compiled, but final scripts are interpreted in navigator, and thus, retaining original source code which makes eval possible. And also, source code is always present for internal reference.

Answer (score 4):

There is no real answer -- a language can be compiled to native code and still contain an `eval` function. Doing so isn't very popular because it requires including essentially a complete compiler in the run-time for every program (at least every one that uses `eval`). There's often a bit of a compromise: instead of including the *complete* compiler, only a rather limited version of the compiler (e.g., missing most optimization) or an interpreter is included.

Answer (score 3):

The notion that compiled languages can't have an `eval` function is simply false.  Most compiled languages choose not implement it due to the complexity but it's achievable. For example

- [C# Mono Eval](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Sep-10.html)
- [C# Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/roslyn)
- LISP

Comment: I should have clarified the question. Since C# things require ALL the .NET framework (including native compiler) is no the case

Comment: @StormByte not sure what you're getting at there

Comment: As Thomas said, I should have stated in question that having eval *without* having all compiler embedded in executable (or library).

Comment: @StormByte then you're asking a question which answers itself. "Can I compile something if I can't use the compiler?"

Comment: No, because in C/C++ for example, you can use the compiler, but you don't have eval (and I think it is not posible in those languages). That is what I meant. .NET executables are always bytecode (despite it can be compiled to native with ngen) when generated, and the .NET library includes both, the runtime and the compiler which is different from C/C++ executables.

Comment: @StormByte i'm not sure what point you're making though. The use of byte code vs. assembly doesn't affect the ability to have eval. The inclusion of the compiler, as a library or exe, is necessary for **any** language to do an eval

Comment: despite I did not make the correct question, reading all responses I have what I wanted, a reasonning of what it is needed to have that functionality. Inclusion of a compiler and reflection :) Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

Compiled languages certainly *can* have eval.

Clojure for instance (along with many other Lisps) is always compiled and supports eval, in line with Lisp's "code is data" philosophy:

```
(def code '(reduce + [1 2 3 4 5]))   ;; create data structure containing code

(eval code)                          ;; compile and execute the code with eval
=> 15
```

All that this technique really requires is that the compiler be included in the language runtime, so that new code can be compiled and executed on-the-fly.

Comment: But there is still one problem, at least on C/C++ (without debugging symbols) is that it does not know anything about variable names (and so on) once compiled, and that was intended in the original question (I should have been stated it clearer)

Comment: @StormByte:  If you're asking about C or C++, then there is no `eval` in either language, and all implementations I've used don't have support for it.  If you're asking about compiled languages in general, then some do embed compilers or interpreters in the runtime, and do have `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that it is reasonable to say that any code that has been heavily optimised during compilation would not be able to handle eval statements. For optimisation to work, the compiler needs to recognise patters in the source that can be optimised. If you need to evaluate a command in the middle of your code, then things need to maintain some flexibility and there will be an associated performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

Compiled languages can certainly have an `eval` function, even for C/C++. You'd just need some way for the runtime to run the compiler, some kind of runtime loading like `dlopen` to load the code that is to be run through `eval` and some way for the eval code to have communicate with the runtime.